# Pointers in c++ pass by value/reference

Tags: c++, pointers

like simple variables ,the pointer variables can also be used as a Value parameter or Reference parameter in functions..... but as the pointer variables are used 2 hold memory location or  content of memory location then what more difference will it make if the pointer variable is used either as Value or as Reference parameter????

Comment: I have an article that might help you a bit: http://mortoray.wordpress.com/2012/01/08/whats-an-object-whats-a-variable/

Answer (score 9):

If function A passes a pointer P by reference to another function B, then B can make P point to a different location in memory, and A will see that change. If, on the other hand, A passes P by value, then B can only change the contents of the memory that P points to. A will see changes to that memory, but P will never point to a *different* spot in memory when B returns.

Comment: Or rather (when passing P by value), P will never point to a different location in memory (you can deconstruct the object and construct a new object in the same place and technically it's a different object)

Answer (score 6):

The difference is as follows:

1. if you pass the pointer *by value*, any changes to the pointer made by the callee **will not** be visible to the caller;
2. if you pass the pointer *by reference*, any changes to the pointer made by the callee **will** be visible to the caller.

Here, I am talking about the value of the pointer itself (i.e. where it points), and not about the value of the pointed-to object.

Answer (score 4):

The small example illustrates the need to pass a pointer by reference

```
//pass by value
void InitString1( char* buf )
{
    buf = new char[5];
}

//pass by reference
void InitString2( char*& buf )
{
    buf = new char[5];
}

int main()
{
    char* buffer = 0;
    InitString1( buffer);
    //buffer is still null and memory leaks
    delete [] buffer;

    InitString2( buffer );
    //buffer will be assigned correctly
    delete [] buffer;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
void passByValue(int* p) {
  p = new int;
}
void passByReference(int*& p) {
  p = new int;
}
int main() {
  int *p1 = 0;
  int *p2 = 0;
  passByValue(p1);
  passByReference(p2);
  std::cout << p1 << "\n";
  std::cout << p2 << "\n";
}
```

Consider the above program. The first line will always print zero, meaning that `main`'s `p1` variable was *not* updated by the call to `passByValue`. In contrast, `p2` *was* updated by the call to `passByRefernce`.