# issues in understanding pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

The following codes are from the book **Programming Interviews Exposed**
I am having problem to understand the concept of pointers. Why can't we use the code no. 1.

**Code no. 1**

```
bool insertInFront( IntElement *head, int data )
{
    IntElement *newElem = new IntElement;
    if( !newElem ) return false;
    newElem->data = data;
    head = newElem; // Incorrect!
    return true;
}
```

**Code no. 2**

```
bool insertInFront( IntElement **head, int data )
{
    IntElement *newElem = new IntElement;
    if( !newElem ) return false;
    newElen->data = data;
    *head = newElem; // Correctly updates head
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Fundamental rule of implementing reference semantics with pointers: The caller takes the address, and the callee dereferences.

Comment: Try something simpler. Write a function that swaps two `int`s using pointers.

Comment: \*before reading anything\* I smell .... **a pipe leakin'**.

Comment: Both of the versions are incorrect for something called `insert`

Comment: Word of warning: both source code pieces are horrible for a number or reasons. Do yourself a favour, don’t learn from this book.

Comment: @KonradRudolph It would be really helpful, if you could suggest me any book for interview related questions for companies like Google, Microsoft etc.

Comment: wtf is this: `if( !newElem ) return false;` *Standard compliant* compilers will not ever return `NULL` from `new`. And even *if* you were on a compiler that returns `NULL` from a failed `new`, the solution is **fail fast**, not return to the caller. The method should be *`void`*. This book is *bad*.

Comment: @Jason What book would you recommend?

Comment: @Amlan Karmakar: CLRS, Algorithms, cover to cover, and LOTS of practice writing code.

Comment: I think this post will help to understand what the author is trying to say is bad: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/8897707/1807078](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8897707/1807078)

Comment: @KonradRudolph for example? Can you please elaborate.

Comment: Best answers to this question are found in the comments. Someone make their comment an answer.

Comment: @Aman • Use of raw pointers. • Check for `nullptr` after `new`. • Pass by pointer instead of pass by reference. • Presence of out parameters (why the boolean return value? Return the new pointer – actually, the boolean is useless anyway, see above). • Lack of encapsulation (this function should be a private member function of a class, and hence return nothing, or maybe a success value.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks. I learned so many new things in these comments. It's a long way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you are calling function 1 as:

```
insertInFront(H, data);
```

Upon calling of a function, the computer makes duplication of arguments, then release them when the function returns. So in code No.1, `head=newElem` assigned the address of `newElem` to `head`(which is a duplicate of `H`), then released `head`, and the address of `newElem` is lost forever. 
In code No.2, however, the function should be called as:

```
insertInFront(&H, data);
```

This means the ADDRESS of `H` is duplicated to `head`, and the address of `newElem` is assigned to `*head`, i.e. where `head` is pointing, which results in `H`. In this way you get the address of `newElem` after the function returns.

Answer (score 4):

- In code 1, you are assigning the pointer location of `newElem` to the *local copy* of `head`. When the function returns, `head` is destroyed, and you will have a memory leak (you lose the pointer to `newElem`, leaving you with no way to `delete` it.) You've only changed the function's *local copy* of the pointer, the caller's copy is unaffected.
- In code 2, `head` is a pointer-to-a-pointer. You don't have just a pointer, you actually have a pointer *to the caller's pointer*. This allows you to alter the caller's pointer, storing the pointer to `newElem` When the function returns, `head` is destroyed, *but it's only the pointer-to-a-pointer*. The original pointer is intact in the caller's scope.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of pointers are very complicated. Basically the way you need to think about pointers are that they are 'values' themselves.  so:

```
*head = some_memory_address_that_points_to_head;
```

could be thought of as:

```
int im_a_pointer_to_head = some_memory_address_value_to_head;
```

So if we apply this same concept to your first function:

```
bool insertInFront(int im_a_pointer_to_head, int data)...
```

You are essentially passing in a copy of the value of your head pointer, changing it within the function only changes the temporary copy made for this function and does not actually change where the original pointer is pointing to.

The second function solves this because you are actually passing in the copy of the pointer that is pointing to the pointer that is pointing to the head (try saying that 3 times fast!).  In this case, you are not changing the copied value, but instead are changing where the actual pointer is pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

To change the value of anything passed via a function argument (and have that change persisted) outside of the function call, you MUST have the memory address of whatever it is whose value you want to change. This is another way of saying that you must "pass by reference" instead of "pass by value" -- otherwise pass by value will cause the function to just alter the COPY.